# Views com php transição com a controller

Tags: php, view, controller

Sou novato em php, e por isso tenho apanhado muito. Até porque tenho usado sublime text com apache e php instalados separadamente (uso Ubuntu com SO). Bom a minha dúvida referente a views e php é:
Não estou entendendo como se faz a transição da controller para a view. Se eu devo misturar código php com as tags html, ou se tem um modo de incluir no arquivo html o que é passado por um código php.

Sei que a minha dúvida é bem genérica e inicial, mas se alguém tiver um exemplo didático de como faço isso, ou se alguém sabe de algum projeto exemplo para eu ver e entender também ajuda.

O que mais tenho encontrado na net é conceito e isso eu já entendi, agora aplicar isso na prática é outros 500

Comment: Não é indicado misturar a view com php, para fazer a conexão entre ambos geralmente usamos um template engine.

Comment: @ricardo podes me passar mais informações sobre esse template enginer? Como expliquei na pergunta, to bem perdido nessa parte, eu to fazendo mvc com 3 camadas model (DAO, Value e Business), só que agora empaquei na questão da view.

Comment: Postei informações como resposta estou ainda aprendendo todas as funcionalidades do Dwoo (um template engine)

Comment: Links onde estou aprendo a trabalhar com o dwoo: http://devzone.zend.com/1746/building-template-driven-web-applications-with-dwoo-part-1/   e   http://devzone.zend.com/1760/building-template-driven-web-applications-with-dwoo-part-2/

Comment: Agradeço sua resposta, mas continuo sem entender a transição, pois eu não queria usar template, queria fazer no braço mesmo para saber como funciona na prática.

Comment: Mas "fazer no braço" não é nem de longe uma opção, pois o meio de campo entre a view e controller não é isolado a uma junção onde há código php dentro de html, uma prova seria abrir um código de template compilado (isso é feito automaticamente) você irá ver que há código PHP dentro de HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Luan,

Você estudando o MVC sem nenhum framework de mercado certo? Para poder ter entender como funciona o e melhorar sua forma de programar, quando esta estudando com PHP fiz um projeto de uma agenda telefonica usando MVC sem framework segue link no meu github:
https://github.com/jmfrolim/MVCSIMPLES

Exemplo do codigo abaixo:

```
<?php
/*
 * Essa classe é responsável por renderizar os arquivos HTML
 * 
 * @package Exemplo simples com MVC
 * @author João Manoel
 * @version 0.1.1
 * 
 * Diretório Pai - lib
 * Arquivo - View.php 
 */
 class View
 {
  /**
  * Armazena o conteúdo HTML
  * @var string
  */
private $st_contents;

/**
* Armazena o nome do arquivo de visualização
* @var string
*/
private $st_view;

 /**
 * Armazena os dados que devem ser mostrados ao reenderizar o 
 * arquivo de visualização
 * @var Array
 */
 private $v_params;

 /**
 * É possivel efetuar a parametrização do objeto ao instanciar o mesmo,
 * $st_view é o nome do arquivo de visualização a ser usado e 
 * $v_params são os dados que devem ser utilizados pela camada de    visualização
* 
* @param string $st_view
* @param Array $v_params
*/
function __construct($st_view = null, $v_params = null) 
{
    if($st_view != null)
        $this->setView($st_view);
    $this->v_params = $v_params;
}   

/**
* Define qual arquivo html deve ser renderizado
* @param string $st_view
* @throws Exception
*/
public function setView($st_view)
{
    if(file_exists($st_view))
        $this->st_view = $st_view;
    else
        throw new Exception("View File '$st_view' don't exists");       
}

/**
* Retorna o nome do arquivo que deve ser renderizado
* @return string 
*/
public function getView()
{
    return $this->st_view;
}

/**
* Define os dados que devem ser repassados à view
* @param Array $v_params
*/
public function setParams(Array $v_params)
{
    $this->v_params = $v_params; 
}

/**
* Retorna os dados que foram ser repassados ao arquivo de visualização
* @return Array
*/
public function getParams()
{
    return $this->v_params;
}

/**
* Retorna uma string contendo todo 
* o conteudo do arquivo de visualiza√ß√£o
* 
* @return string
*/
public function getContents()
{
    ob_start();
    if(isset($this->st_view))
        require_once $this->st_view;
    $this->st_contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $this->st_contents;   
}

/**
* Imprime o arquivo de visualização 
*/
public function showContents()
{
    echo $this->getContents();
    exit;
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Obrigado por teres melhorado a resposta, assimfica mais completo. A ideia como percebeste é que outros no futuro possam aprender com as respostas. Até breve!

Comment: Por nada, eu é que agradeço por me ajudar acontribuir da melhor forma possivel!

Comment: Agradeço gente, eu to entendendo agora as coisas, ainda um pouco confusas mas eu chego lá. Fiz uma meio gambiarra mvc na hora de exibir os dados coletados. Mas vou tentar seguir isso que que vcs passaram, vou baixar seu exemplo também para entender melhor. Valeu pela força.

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue, pode ser o momento de você incluir seus testes na sua questão para podermos auxiliar no caminho.

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é uma boa prática misturar o `controller` (lógica do sistema) com a `view` (parte visual do programa que interfaceia com o usuário), para nos evadir dos problemas acarretados por esta mistura e ganharmos mais segurança operacional (o Web Designer e o Desenvolvedor podem trabalhar ao mesmo tempo sem que o trabalho de um interfira no outro) é usado `templates`.

Exemplos de templates:

**Smarty:** [Link para download e documentação](http://www.smarty.net/)

**Dwoo:** [Link para download e documentação](http://dwoo.org/)

Exemplo de uso (na documentação é fornecido mais exemplos para outras funcionalidades):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <blockquote>

    Palavra 1 <br/>
    Palavra 2 <br/>
    {$nome}      <br/>
    {$sobrenome}
    </blockquote>

  </body>
</html>

<?php
// auto-loader
include 'dwooAutoload.php';

// cria objeto Dwoo 
$dwoo = new Dwoo();

// le o templete acima definido
$tpl = new Dwoo_Template_File('tmpl/knock.tpl');

// valores dinamicos que serão injetados no template
$data = array();
$data['nome'] = 'Bill';
$data['sobrenome'] = 'Gates';

// injeta os valores e exibe a pagina, note que o nome do indices são identicos as 
//variaveis dentro do template, o dwoo irá fazer a injeção paseado nos nomes identicos.
$dwoo->output($tpl, $data);
?>
```